# Show section of visualforce page on checkbox click

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport

I have a visualforce form- included in this form are three checkboxes. Two of the checkboxes are additional questions following on from the first, so I only want them to show on the page when the first checkbox is clicked to true.

I have tried to do this using actionSupport, but it seems to have broken my checkbox (label not showing) and the actionSupport doesn't seem to cause the additional checkboxes to rerender. Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputField value="{! custom.cloneProductsBool__c }" label="Clone Products" required="true">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="checkboxes"/>
                </apex:inputField>
                <apex:outputPanel id="checkboxes" rendered="{! custom.cloneProductsBool__c}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{! custom.removeDiscountsBool__c }" label="Remove discounts"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! custom.removeNumbersBool__c }" label="Remove Numbers" />
                </apex:outputPanel>               
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: this is a classic VF error - well explained by the inestimable [Bob Buzzard blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue when you try to reRender a conditionally rendered outputPanel (because it was never in the DOM to begin with). Add the conditional rendering on the individual fields or a sub tag from the outputPanel as follows (I tested and works just fine)

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Checkbox1__c }">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="checkboxes" />
    </apex:inputField>
    <apex:outputPanel id="checkboxes">
        <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Checkbox2__c }" label="Remove discounts" rendered="{!Account.Checkbox1__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Checkbox3__c }" label="Remove Numbers" rendered="{!Account.Checkbox1__c}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```